# Display multiples sums in an table with emberjs/handlebars

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm working on a personnal project based on ember and I'm a bit stuck with something I'd like to implement :

I need to be able to display a table (based on the model of an ArrayController) and inside this table I need to display a column summing all values from another column for all the previous rows.

I know how to sum all rows into only one value, but I don't know how to do that for every rows.

Here is what I need to achieve :

```
__________________________
   value    |     sum
__________________________
     1      |      1
__________________________
     2      |      3
__________________________
    -1      |      2
```

and so on...

"value" is a field for each DS.Model in the model of my ArrayController.

I'm not looking for the final implementation but some hints on how to achieve this.

Thanks for reading me,

Pierre.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

(javascript)

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    inc: function () {
      this.get("model")[1].incrementProperty("val");
    }
  }
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var a = App.Model.create({
      val: 1
    });
    var b = App.Model.create({
      val: 2,
      prev: a
    });
    var c = App.Model.create({
      val: -1,
      prev: b
    });
    return [a, b, c];
  }
});

App.Model = Ember.Object.extend({
  val: 0,
  prev: null,
  sum: function () {
    var val = this.get("val"),
        prev = this.get("prev");
    if (!prev) {
      return val;
    }
    return prev.get("sum") + val;
  }.property("val", "prev.sum")
});
```

(template)

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <ul>
    {{#each item in model}}
      <li>{{item.val}} | {{item.sum}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
    <button type="button" {{action inc}}>Inc</button>
  </script>
```

Working example [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nihixoji/1/)

The only caveat, you have to create and maintain the links between the elements. If you reshuffle the array, add new elements etc... you have to recreate all the references manually.

---

**Update:**

I'm intrigued by this problem, so I gave it another go.

```js
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var col = [];
    col.push(App.Model.create({
      val: 1,
      all: col
    }));
    col.push(App.Model.create({
      val: 2,
      all: col
    }));
    col.push(App.Model.create({
      val: -1,
      all: col
    }));
    return col;
  }
});

App.Model = Ember.Object.extend({
  val: 0,
  all: null,
  prev: function () {
    var all = this.get("all");
    for (var i = 0; i < all.length - 1; i++) {
      if (all[i + 1] === this) {
        return all[i];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }.property("all.[]"),
  sum: function () {
    var val = this.get("val"),
        prev = this.get("prev");
    if (!prev) {
      return val;
    }
    return prev.get("sum") + val;
  }.property("val", "prev.sum")
});
```

Updated live demo is [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nihixoji/3/edit).

This will track changes in parent collection and automatically determine the `previous` element.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. This is pretty cool but I'm displaying the arrangedContent ordered by date and the dates can be edited so the order can change. I don't know if something could be done to work without the references.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is, as far as I know, there is no natural way for a collection element to bind to its collection. You CAN try setting up a reference manually. Eg. instead of `prev`, having a property `all` that references the collection/ArrayController, and then listening to all collection changes and recalculating. But that would probably not be very performant.

Comment: Updated the answer with an improved version using reference to the parent collection.

Comment: I got an idea reading your answer but I don't know if it's something acceptable ember-wise : I'm adding an arrangedContent property on the controller which sort the model based on the "order" property (which is supposed to be a date) and then returning a wrapper object like : {item: myItem, sum: sum}. This property is refreshed on a change on every order/val property on my items. What do you think ?
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nihixoji/2/edit

Comment: The problem is, this will recreate the whole list (objects and array) if any property changes. If you have DOM bound to these, it will be redrawn as well. This CAN be fine, it depends on your use case (as in how often you change the values and under which circumstances).